# Select first N items in a Google BigQuery Repeated Field

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to select the first n items in a Google BigQuery Repeated field?

Looking at an example from Google's documentation:

```
WITH items AS
    (SELECT ["apples", "bananas", "pears", "grapes"] as list
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ["coffee", "tea", "milk" ] as list
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ["cake", "pie"] as list)

SELECT list, list[OFFSET(0)] as offset_1, list[OFFSET(1)] as offset_2
FROM items;
```

gives the following:

[image: Bigquery SQL Output]

The OFFSET() function returns a single (Non-Repeated) element.

Is there a elegant way to select the first n (say n=2) elements in a Repeated field?  Looking at row 1, the output should be a Repeated field with two elements: apples and bananas.

Comment: Can you include the expected output as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH items AS (
  SELECT ["apples", "bananas", "pears", "grapes"] AS list UNION ALL
  SELECT ["coffee", "tea", "milk" ] AS list UNION ALL
  SELECT ["cake", "pie"] AS list
)
SELECT 
  list AS original_list, 
  ARRAY(SELECT item FROM UNNEST(list) item WITH OFFSET pos WHERE pos < 2) new_list
FROM items
```

with output as

```sql
Row original_list   new_list     
1   apples          apples   
    bananas         bananas  
    pears        
    grapes       
2   coffee          coffee   
    tea             tea  
    milk         
3   cake            cake     
    pie             pie
```